# Having Google Drive File Picker not appear as a popup and abstract information from google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to make it possible for the Google drive SDK to be present at all times. Currently it only appears as a popup when I refresh the page and if I were to close it, it would disappear. I would like to know how will I be able to leave it present at all times as well as being able to abstract information from the user file and list it in a table.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">
</script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
 data-src="http://example.com/pug-snores.mp3"
 data-filename="pug-snores.mp3"
 data-sitename="Pictures of pugs">
</div>


<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad">
</script>
<script>
 function onApiLoad() {
  gapi.load('auth',{'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
  gapi.load('picker');
 }

 function onAuthApiLoad() {
  window.gapi.auth.authorize({
  'client_id': 'client_id',
  'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
  },handleAuthResult);
 }

 var oauthToken;
 function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
   oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
   createPicker();
   }
 }

 function createPicker() {
  var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
  .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
  .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())
  .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
  .setDeveloperKey('')
  .build();
  picker.setVisible(true);
 }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <title>Google Picker Example</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?           onload=onApiLoad"></script>
    <script>
        function onApiLoad() {
            gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
            gapi.load('picker');
        }
        function onAuthApiLoad() {
            window.gapi.auth.authorize({
                'client_id': 'client_id',
                'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
            }, handleAuthResult);
        }
        var oauthToken;
        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
                createPicker();
            }
        }
        function createPicker() {
            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsView())
                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                //.setDeveloperKey('')
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
        }

        function pickerCallback(data) {
            var url = 'nothing';
            if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
                var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
                url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
            }
            var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
        }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="result"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.jsonload=onApiLoad"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

If you need more information please feel free to ask and for those who answer my questions. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Its not called "SDK"

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use the google picker in any other form than a popup. The only way to simulate it is by using the drive api to build a similar UI than the filepicker. Doable but a lot of work.